# QAbstractItemModel::match() not searching entire model

Tags: c++, qt, qabstractitemmodel

The [Qt documentation](http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qt.html#MatchFlag-enum) states that calling `QAbstractItemModel::match()` with the `Qt::MatchRecursive` and `Qt::MatchWrap` flags set will search through the "entire hierarchy" and "when the search reaches the last item in the **model**, it begins again at the first item and continues until all items have been examined."

However, in my example, this is not the case. `match()` only searches through the child/sibling items of the `start` index.

I'm trying to implement a simple "Next" and "Previous" search feature that searches for text within a `QTreeView`. But since `match()` won't search through the parent/upper-level items, it quits too early.

Here is my "next" function:

```
QModelIndex searchStartIndex;
if(!treeView->currentIndex().isValid())
    searchStartIndex = treeView->model()->index(0,0);//root item
else
    searchStartIndex = treeView->currentIndex();

QModelIndexList nextMatches = treeView->model()->match(searchStartIndex, Qt::DisplayRole, lineEdit->text(), 1, Qt::MatchContains | Qt::MatchWrap | Qt::MatchRecursive);

if(nextMatches.size() == 1)
{
    //first result might be the currently selected item
    if(nextMatches.at(0) == treeView->currentIndex())
    {
        nextMatches = treeView->model()->match(searchStartIndex, Qt::DisplayRole, lineEdit->text(), 2, Qt::MatchContains | Qt::MatchWrap | Qt::MatchRecursive);

        if(nextMatches.size() == 2)
        {
            treeView->setCurrentIndex(nextMatches.at(1));
        }
    }
    else
        treeView->setCurrentIndex(nextMatches.at(0));
}
```

I don't understand why the docs say one thing, but it behaves differently.

Comment: Qt::MatchRecursive searches through the entire hierarchy of the children, otherwise the "start" parameter would have no meaning, on the other hand Qt::MatchWrap does the same but with the sub-node since it would not make sense to set the parameters "start"

Comment: start, one would assume, would be the starting item within the model-wide wrapping method.

Comment: so do not assume, check the source code: https://github.com/radekp/qt/blob/master/src/corelib/kernel/qabstractitemmodel.cpp#L2037 :)

Comment: If one is expected to read the source code after every time the documentation is read, nothing would get done. The documentation says in pure english, it examines all items in the model. And it only says the "start" item says where the search should begin and end. It says NOTHING about limiting it to the starting items child items.

When you read that, there is no question about what's it's saying. So no reason to read source code until after the problem was identified.

Comment: Exactly, it sounds like a bug in the docs, and it happens very often, report it :)

Comment: I might, but you cant say that I should have read the source because i assumed something lol. Of course i assumed something, it was written that way XD

Comment: I only check the source code when something does not work as the docs say, in other cases there is no need, that is what I try to say.

Comment: My larger point is... i was stuck. Unsure how to proceed where documentation failed me. I logic'd my way around it however and coded my own implementation since

Comment: That is what should be done, Qt does not implement everything, and what we lack we must implement it :)